# How to use Apigee PHP SDK with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, apigee

I've created a few services on Apigee using their appservices and I'm trying to use the Apigee php SDK with Laravel, however I have no idea how to get this library working. I followed the first 2 lines of the guide, then added the Apache>Usergrid folders from the SDK under a new directory app>classes. After moving the namespaces round in the Usergrid classes it was fine (Laravel was complaining about namespace declarations not being on the first line of the script). Every time I try to 'start the client' as per the instructions I simply get a file not found i.e.

```
$client = new Apache\Usergrid\Client('1hotrod','sandbox');
```

I have included it in the app>start>global.php file and tried including it in the autoload of my composer.json then running composer dump autoload.

The SDK is here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/tree/master/sdks/php

I can call the API using cURL from my controller but I was hoping to make use of the SDK. Can anyone give me some help on how to start using this library? I'm completely lost

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: i did manage to get it working yeah. what i did was create a package using the workbench. Useful resources:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages 
http://toddish.co.uk/blog/creating-a-custom-laravel-4-auth-driver/

You can just use the classes exactly as they come, you just need register a new provider then, for example, you can set your apigee credentials in your package config file

let me know if you need more info though - it's a bit long to post in a comment on here but there are a number of resources available on the internet around creating and registering new packages